# Приведение времени в нужный формат с помощью pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

> В таблице данные в формате csv. Есть столбец с указание времени, но время выводится слитно. Подскажите как привести время к нормальному формату?
>   часы:07 минуты:45 секунды:55 микросекунды:000

```
     time
074555000
074556000
074557000
074558000
074559000
074600000
074601000
074602000
074603000
074604000
074605000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [15]: df = pd.read_csv(filename)

In [16]: df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%H%M%S%f').dt.time

In [17]: df
Out[17]:
        time
0   07:45:55
1   07:45:56
2   07:45:57
3   07:45:58
4   07:45:59
5   07:46:00
6   07:46:01
7   07:46:02
8   07:46:03
9   07:46:04
10  07:46:05

In [18]: df.dtypes
Out[18]:
time    object
dtype: object
```